# Why is my launchd job running at boot even with RunAtLoad key set to false?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a launchd plist file that I use to run a program at a selected time every day. It works, but it also runs the program whenever I boot the computer or unload and reload the job using the GUI program LaunchControl---*even though I have the `RunAtLoad` key set to false?*

The complete plist file is below; it is located in `/Library/LaunchAgents/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.adbot.plist</string>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/wcm1/programming/ricedh/adbot/adbot.py</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.adbot.plist.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.adbot.plist.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It appears that my `KeepAlive` definition was implying `RunAtLoad`, and even overriding my attempt to set `RunAtLoad` to false. Not sure why this is the case, but taking out the `KeepAlive` block seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

You likely have an interaction between the `SuccessfulExit` and `RunAtLoad` keys. The [launchd plist manual](https://manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/) page mentions an inversion takes place if `RunAtLoad` is set
:

> **SuccessfulExit**
>
> If true, the job will be restarted as long as the program exits and with an exit status of zero.
>
> If false, the job will be restarted in the inverse condition.  This key implies that "RunAtLoad" is set to true, since the job needs to run at least once  before we can get an exit status.

Others have struggled with this behaviour, see [launchd ignores RunAtLoad=false](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21333169#21333169).